# Accessing a private GitHub repository for deploying Blockchain on Bluemix

Tags: git, github, ibm-cloud, blockchain

I'm currently stuck in trying to access a private repository on GitHub for a new service I created for Blockchain on Bluemix.
I'm able to directly connect my public githib repository with Bluemix to deploy my Blockchain chaincode. The same I'm unable to do so via private githib repository.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Bluemix user but use a lot of Github integrations.
First thing you can try to do is to create new project, try to do one of the following:

If you're using Continuous Delivery toolchains, you should find what you need here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/pipeline_working.html

If you're not yet using toolchains, try the previous version of the Delivery Pipeline service documentation: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/DeliveryPipeline/index.html

Also you can try to create a new project, connect your gihub account and check the permissions on github's auth page carefully to make sure you grant access to private repos.

It's also looks like there still some problems with organisation accounts repositories.